# How i can calculate sum of n based on id?

Tags: django, python-3.x, group-by, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet like this. I want sum of "n" based on "id".

this is my queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'n': 0}, {'id': 2, 'n': 0}, {'id': 2, 'n': 1}, {'id': 3, 'n': 2}, {'id': 4, 'n': 0}, {'id': 5, 'n': 1}, {'id': 5, 'n': 0}]>
```

and this is my code:

```
drivers = Driver.objects.values('id').annotate(
        travel_time=Sum(Case(
            When(car__ride__pickup_time__isnull=False,
                 then=(F('car__ride__dropoff_time') - F('car__ride__pickup_time'))),
            default=0
        )),
    ).annotate(
        n=Case(
            When(Q(travel_time__gt=t) & Q(car__model__gte=n), then=Count('car__ride')),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
            default=0
        )
    ).values('id', 'n')
```

i dont know how to make a group by based on id :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by in django using `values`

in your queryset you are grouping it by `.values('id', 'n')` and `.values('id')`

remove the `.values('id', 'n')` and it should work.

```
drivers = Driver.objects.values('id').annotate(
        travel_time=Sum(Case(
            When(car__ride__pickup_time__isnull=False,
                 then=(F('car__ride__dropoff_time') - F('car__ride__pickup_time'))),
            default=0
        )),
    ).annotate(
        n=Case(
            When(Q(travel_time__gt=t) & Q(car__model__gte=n), then=Count('car__ride')),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
            default=0
        )
    ).values_list('id', 'n')
```

and it should work